# C# pretty code print library

Tags: c#, c, dll, format

please does anyone know if there is c# library for formatting C based codes? I'm writing some code generators for myself and it would be nice to have code which comes out of my app formatted. I was looking for some but it's hard to find.

Thanks.

Comment: It's asking the community to recommend something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one I have ever tried with marginal success was.

http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/manual/indent.html

Comment: looks like it is intended for linux shell, isn't it?

Comment: True but I believe people have ported it.  I just cant find the project. ill look around

Comment: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/indent.htm

Comment: cool thanks :) I'll manage from now